# Descargar adjuntos de outlook con c#

Tags: c#, descarga, outlook

quiero descargar archivos adjuntos en un correo de outlook con c#, si embargo por algunos temas no puedo crear una contraseña de aplicacion, entonces necesito una forma de pasar la verificacion de dos pasos, hice una app que se conectaba a una api y podia mandar correo, pero no se puede descargar desde ahí. Si alguien me pudiera orientar sería genial.

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Revisa el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio. 3. Revisa cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 4. Finalmente que no te sorprenda que te cierren la pregunta tal cual está, para entender los motivos, revisa el contenido de los enlaces mencionados. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.